# XmlHttpRequest requesting an ArrayBuffer results in garbage

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I making an `XmlHttpRequest` to download a binary file as an `ArrayBuffer`:

```
async function downloadBinaryFile(fileName : string) : Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', `someFolder/${fileName}`, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        request.onload = function(event) {
            const arrayBuffer = request.response;
            if (arrayBuffer)
                resolve(arrayBuffer)
            else
                reject('empty array buffer');
        };
        request.onerror = reject;
        request.send();
    });
}
```

This works... most of the time. That means it works reliably for all external binary files I tried, but not for the ones I created myself. This suggests that the problems lies with my files, but I can request those via Postman and they come out fine as well as upload them to an external website that can use them. So the problem should not be my files either.

The content of those `ArrayBuffers` should be 72 `float` values (representing 24 vertices of a cube) and 36 `unsigned short` values (representing 12 indices). The values somehow retain certain pattern, so they are not completely random, but I do not see what goes wrong. The Buffers also have completely unrealistic sizes like 216840 bytes for a 288 byte file. For example:

```
[-0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
 -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
 ... ]
```

becomes

```
[-0.800000011920929, 0, 0,
 -0.5666700005531311, 0, 0,
 -0.3957499861717224, 0, 0,
 ... ]
```

I am honestly stuck. This is not an issue of endianness, I can request the same url for the file as in the XHR with postman and receive the correct file and the same code works for other files. What else could be at fault?

(for the sake of completeness: this was tested on Chrome 74, and the files were served using Nginx 1.16.0 on Windows)